# Eval Error with Webpack 4 + Babel 7 chunks

Tags: webpack, microsoft-edge, babeljs, webpack-4

Babel 7 + Webpack 4 chunks not loading in Edge. Working in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

When I load a page and my entry js file (build.js), edge then tries to load what I assume is a chunk but loads something like the following.

https://www.myurl.com/mypage/eval%20code%20(36297)

There are no errors in the console.

I've tried updating my babel config to include different presets/plugins and updated by .browserslistrc to be 'defaults' which has worked in the past.

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(false);

    const presets = [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                "corejs": 3,
            },
        ],
    ].filter(Boolean);

    const plugins = [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",

    ].filter(Boolean);

    return {
        presets,
        plugins,
    };
};
```

.browserslistrc

```
defaults
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    stats: {
        children: true,
    },
    entry: [
        "core-js/modules/es.promise",
        "core-js/modules/es.array.iterator",
        './application/resources/js/app.js',
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
        publicPath: assets_path,
        filename: 'js/build.js',
        chunkFilename: 'js/chunk.[chunkhash].js',
    },
    performance: {
        hints: "warning",
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin(),
            new TerserPlugin({
                sourceMap: true,
            }),
        ],
    },
    plugins: getPlugins(),
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            },

            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './application/'),
                    /vue2-datatable-component/,
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.styl(us)?$/,
                loader: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'stylus-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            implementation: require('sass'),
                            fiber: require('fibers'),
                            indentedSyntax: true, // optional
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Microsoft Edge browser are you using? Based on [this document](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration#babel-runtime-babel-plugin-transform-runtime), if you need core-js support with transform-runtime, you would now pass the corejs option and use the @babel/runtime-corejs2 dependency instead of @babel/runtime. Like this:

```
# install the runtime as a dependency
npm install @babel/runtime-corejs2
# install the plugin as a devDependency
npm install @babel/plugin-transform-runtime --save-dev
```

and

```
{
  "plugins": [
-   ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
+   ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
+     "corejs": 2,
+   }],
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm using Edge 42.17134.1.0. EdgeHTML 17.17134.

The above did not work. I've attempted all different configs, corejs2, corejs3. No luck. The exact same configuration that works in chrome, firefox, safari and opera has this issue with edge.

Comment: I tested with webpack and babel on my Edge following this sample:https://www.valentinog.com/blog/babel/. It is working fine. Could you send us a mini sample so we see how to help?